# Ask/answer date for community wiki posts should always be shown in the "owner" (rightmost) user card/user info

Tags: feature-request, status-review, design, community-wiki, timestamps

I just noticed that the "asked" and "answered" datetimes for Community Wiki questions:

[image] <sub>(from [.NET: bool vs enum as a method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908876/net-bool-vs-enum-as-a-method-parameter))</sub>

And answers:

[image] <sub>(from [How to loop through userform until selection is made or exit is hit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67615640/how-to-loop-through-userform-until-selection-is-made-or-exit-is-hit/67626855#67626855))</sub>

have jumped over to the middle of the 'post' column, rather than remain above the author name in the 'author card' area.

An edit to the post overwrites the "asked/answered" information altogether:

[image] <sub>(again from [How to loop through userform until selection is made or exit is hit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67615640/how-to-loop-through-userform-until-selection-is-made-or-exit-is-hit/67626855#67626855))</sub>

---

Some existing (as of this edit) examples of the problem:

- Answer: [.NET: bool vs enum as a method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908876/net-bool-vs-enum-as-a-method-parameter/2908896#2908896)
- Question: [How can I make Ansible interpret a variable inside a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408680/how-can-i-make-ansible-interpret-a-variable-inside-a-variable)

---

(I made sure to turn off all userscripts and adblockers to rule those out)

Comment: Strange that for questions, you don't have a date link but for answers there is a link?

Comment: @10Rep I agree, it is strange

Comment: Did they change it yet ?

Comment: @OmarTougui To answer your question, no, it's not been fixed.

Comment: What did it look like originally, for a community wiki post that hasn't been edited yet? Because it seems like it's been this way [since at least 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20170310104954/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript) (possibly earlier). As far as I can tell, this happens specifically for community-wiki posts that don't have any additional revisions.

Comment: [Here's an even older example from 2012.](https://web.archive.org/web/20120217181050/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42/best-way-to-allow-plugins-for-a-php-application) I'm guessing this is by design, but I'll check with the devs.

Comment: Then this should be a feature request. I know it's something that I've looked for multiple times on CW posts in the "normal" location and been frustrated at not seeing it, and not having it available at all once the post has been edited.

Comment: @V2Blast There's a fair chance it always looked like this and I never realized it, but if that is the case, then I agree with Makyen that it should be a feature-request to make it behave the same way as normal posts--seeing the original post date is useful information even for CW posts, IMHO.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest making that feature request as a new post on MSE (if there isn't already a feature request there about it – which there doesn't seem to be). And it should probably explain the reasoning for the request as well.